# daterange with timerange using codeigniter 3 and ajax

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have a daterange picker and it is fully working. However, I have a **new target** which is **daterange with timepicker**. But the thing is **I don't know how to implement it like what I did on my daterange without timepicker**. Is there any way where I can implement it? I have provided my codes below of my fully working daterange picker. I have provided also my screenshot of my current daterange and my target daterange with timepicker. Thank you in advance.

[image: An image of my current datepicker and my target datepicker with timepicker]

**HTML:**

```
<div class="img-fluid">
    <div class="input-group">
  From:
  <input type="date" class="mr-4" id="from" name="from">
   To:
  <input type="date"  id="to" name="to" style="margin-right:50px;"> 

  </div>
 </div>

<div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="custom-tabs-two-1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="custom-tabs-two-1-tab">
<table id="testing" class="table-striped table table-head-fixed" style="min-width:1000px; width:100%;">
     <thead class="" style="background-color: #404040; color: white;">
           <tr>
                 <th scope="col"><i class="fas fa-list-ol mr-2"></i>Transaction ID</th> 
                       <th scope="col"><i class="fas fa-list-ol mr-2"></i>Reference No.</th> 
                       <th scope="col"><i class="far fa-calendar-alt mr-2"></i>Date Requested</th>

         </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
      </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```

**Script & Ajax:**

```
var save_method; //for save method string
    var table;
    var base_url = '<?php echo base_url();?>';
     
    $(document).ready(function() {
     
        //datatables
       var table = $('#testing').DataTable({ 
             dom: 'lBfrtip',
             buttons: [
                'print', 'csv', 'copy', 'excel', 'pdfHtml5'
            ],
           
            "processing": false, //Feature control the processing indicator.
            "serverSide": true, //Feature control DataTables' server-side processing mode.    
            "order": [], //Initial no order.
            
     
            // Load data for the table's content from an Ajax source
            "ajax": {
                "url": "<?php echo site_url('controller/ajax_list')?>",
                "type": "POST",
                 "data": function ( data ) {
                     data.from = $('#from').val();
                        data.to = $('#to').val();
           
        
         
                },
                
            },
     
            //Set column definition initialization properties.
            "columnDefs": [
                { 
                    "targets": [ 0 ], //first column
                    "orderable": false, //set not orderable
                },
                { 
                    "targets": [ -1 ], //last column
                    "orderable": false, //set not orderable
                },
     
            ],
     
        });


        setInterval( function () {
      testing.ajax.reload(null,false);
}, 1000);
```

**Controller:**

```
  public function ajax_list()
    {
        
       $list = $this->repo->admin();
        $data = array();
        $no = $_POST['start'];
        foreach ($list as $person) {
            $no++;
            $row = array();
            $row[] = $person->transID;
            $row[] = $person->refNumber; 
            $row[] = $person->dateRequested;
   
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        
        $output = array(
            "draw" => $_POST['draw'],
            "recordsTotal" => $this->repo->showing_pending(),
            "recordsFiltered" => $this->repo->count_filtered(),
            "data" => $data,
        );
        //output to json format
        echo json_encode($output);
    }
}
```

**Model:**

```
    var $table = 'ca';
    var $column_order = array(null,'transID','dateRequested','refNumber');
    var $order = array('transID' => 'desc');
    var $column_search = array('transID','dateRequested','refNumber');

    //set column field database for datatable orderable      //set column field database for datatable searchable just firstname , lastname , address are searchable     var $order = array('id' => 'desc'); // default order
    
    
    
    private function _get_datatables_query()
    {

        if($this->input->post('from')){
         
            
            $this->db->where('dateCre >=', $this->input->post('from'));
            $this->db->where('dateCre <=', $this->input->post('to'));
            
        }
        
        $this->db->from('ca');
  
    
        
        $i = 0;
        
        foreach ($this->column_search as $item) 
        {
            if($_POST['search']['value']) 
            {
                
                if($i===0) // first loop
                {
                    $this->db->group_start(); 
                    $this->db->like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
                }
                else
                {
                    $this->db->or_like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
                }
                
                if(count($this->column_search) - 1 == $i) 
                    $this->db->group_end(); 
            }
            $i++;
        }
        
        if(isset($_POST['order'])) 
        {
            $this->db->order_by($this->column_order[$_POST['order']['0']['column']], $_POST['order']['0']['dir']);
        }
        else if(isset($this->order))
        {
            $order = $this->order;
            $this->db->order_by(key($order), $order[key($order)]);
        }
    }
    

    function admin()
    {
        $this->_get_datatables_query();
        if($_POST['length'] != -1)
            $this->db->limit($_POST['length'], $_POST['start']);
            $query = $this->db->get();
            return $query->result();
    }


    public function showing_pending()
    {
        $this->db->from($this->table);
        return $this->db->count_all_results();
    }

    
    function count_filtered()
    {
        
        $this->_get_datatables_query();
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->num_rows();
    }



}
```

Answer (score 1):

What is your exact error? I think that you need to sanitize your post values before the query.
Change This:

```
        $this->db->where('dateCre >=', $this->input->post('from'));
```

To this (please select the correct format in your case)

```
$from_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y h:m:s', $this->input->post('from'));
            $this->db->where('dateCre >=', $from_date->format('Y-m-d h:m:s'));
```

Do it also with the "post('to')" value.